# Textview.setText(addressString) returns null value error

Tags: android, textview

I have to set a String value dynamically to a textview in android, but unfortunately I got null value error but in the log I can print the value of String.So I am sure that the string is not null but pretty large.
here is my logcat results:

```
2-06 16:05:39.930  11631-11631/sarath.com.reachmeE/from_address﹕ Sub Jail Rd, Talap
Kannur, Kerala 670002
11.877453, 75.372992
12-06 16:05:39.940  11631-11631/sarath.com.reachmeE/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sarath.com.reachme/sarath.com.reachme.app.Mapview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sarath.com.reachme.app.Mapview.onCreate(Mapview.java:95)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
```

here is my code snippet:

```
Log.e("addrs short", String.valueOf(from_address));
address.setText(String.valueOf(from_address));
```

Is there any limit in size/length for the string which can displayed by the textview ?

Comment: try to debug your code

Comment: what is on this line Mapview.java:95

Comment: Is your textView initialized?

Comment: error starts at `sarath.com.reachme.app.Mapview.onCreate(Mapview.java:95)` whats there?

Comment: line 95: address.setText(String.valueOf(from_address));                if i comment this line it works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO limits on the size of the string. almost sure that the error is that address `TextView` is null, this may happen if you do `findElementById(R.id.your_address_id);` but the View `(R.id.your_address_id)` is in another Activity.

Answer (score 1):

may be you not give any reference to your address field that's why you getting this error.

```
address = (TextView) findElementById(R.id.your_address_id);
```

Comment: can you please edit your question and post whole code for that activity, so we can find some solution for you.

Comment: the code is somehing pretty lengthier one..nearly 700 lines or more..one more point I have to mention here is that, the string value is fetch from the json array got as response of google distance matrix api